# semi responsive image depends on width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that 's 600px wide and I have an image inside of it. I want the image to have a maximum width of 600px but I don't want the image to be 100% to make it responsive.

A better example is if I have an image width is less than 600px don't make it responsive but if it's greater than 600 make it responsive.

```html
<div style="max-width: 600px; width: 100%">
  <img src="some-image.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ***`wrong`*** if you use :

```
img {
  width:100%
  max-width:600px;
}
```

because if image width be `less than` 600px ,width increase to 600px.

***So,use this code:***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div img').each(function(){
    if($(this).width() > 600)
      $(this).width('100%');
  })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div img').each(function(){
    if($(this).width() > 600)
      $(this).width('100%');
  })
})
```

```css
div {
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}

.big {
  width: 1000px;
}

.small {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<div>
    <img class="big" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="">
</div> 

<div>
    <img class="small" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQz4hmigjfluBw-XIRxktTzQoc3yTiydqVx-Z1zephGPtq_Cuf1WA" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For image use **width:100%** and **height:auto**
and for container use **max-width:600px**;
it makes your image resopnsive.

Comment: comment if you have any query on my answer

Answer (score 0):

Assign the `width` controlling CSS to the image, not the `<div>`. Any `width` value on the container `<div>` will restrict the enclosed `img`. Easier to see than explain (at least for me). For example:

```css
img {
 max-width:350px;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px;background:#0ff"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" /><br />
200 wide</div>
<div style="width:350px;background:#0f0"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" /><br />
350 wide</div>
<div style="width:400px;background:#ff0"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" /><br />
400 wide</div>
<div style="width:100%;background:#f77"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" /><br />
full width</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try bootstrap.. bootstrap having built in class for making images responsive.. try below this code

```
 <img class="img-responsive" src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
```